# android - how to play a gif in an android application activity instead of a steady ImageView

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-activity, android-widget

Okay, I've checked, this question never really got a good answer so I'm doing a follow-up and hope someone can help, doing an Imageview is easy (just a drag & drop and then some styling & referencing) but how do we really put a gif in an activity THE EASY WAY. Let's say our gif's name is mygif1 and it's in the resources folder under raw. I'd like it to play in my activity called activity1 in loop while it lasts, Should I create a class especially for that gif or can I make all the references in activity1, what type do I use in Layout to reference it? Can I make it painless or do i have to create 5 classes and 500 lines of code? An example with this data would be much appreciated :)

Comment: By "play a gif", do you mean that this is an animated GIF?

Answer (score 0):

See this gist [gif utils](https://gist.github.com/garymabin/d37480095b7469bd2a1a), use it like below:

```
final ImageView v = ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.gif_test));
AnimatedGifDrawable drawable = new AnimatedGifDrawable(getResources()
        .openRawResource(R.drawable.gif_image), null, 3);
drawable.setOneShot(false);
v.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```